# JavaScript SyntaxError: invalid property id

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute the following JS code;

```
var foo = {
  func1:function(){
    function test()
    {
      alert("123");
    }();
    alert("456");
  },
  myVar : 'local'
};
```

But I am getting an error 
SyntaxError: invalid property id

What is wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 11):

You have a syntax error:

```
var foo = {
    func1:function() {
        function test() {
            alert("123");
        }();
//       ^ You can't invoke a function declaration
        alert("456");
    },
    myVar : 'local'
};
```

Assuming you wanted an immediately-invoked function, you'll have to make that function parse as an expression instead:

```
var foo = {
    func1:function() {
        (function test() {
//      ^ Wrapping parens cause this to be parsed as a function expression
            alert("123");
        }());
        alert("456");
    },
    myVar : 'local'
};
```

Answer (score 3):

wrap with `()`:

```
(function test(){
  alert("123");
}());
```

Or:

```
(function test(){
  alert("123");
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it's very different, adding the answer here for others who might come across the same error.

I have an object like below

```
var obj = {
  case: ''
};
```

so when referring to the `case` attribute as `obj. case`, as `case` is a reserved word, my editor `codeMirror` raised an error.

After I renamed it from `case` to `caseNumber` it worked well.
Similarly cant use `if`, `else` or `switch` and other JS keywords even as attributes as well.